# Can we pass global variable as parameter to a variable value in Robot framework?

Tags: robotframework

I need to pass the value stored in a global variable into another value of a variable.

Scenario :

1. I am Fetching a value from DB using SQL query and storing it in a global variable.
2. Now I would need to check whether the fetched value satisfies the
   required condition for further testing. So in order achieve this I
   need the pass the fetched value into second SQL query

Below is example code

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Process
Library           DatabaseLibrary
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${query}      SQL statement to fetch value from a table
${query2}     SQL statement to check condition whether the ${query1} fetch 
              value satisfies required conditions

***Test Cases***
LINES TO CONNECT TO Db
${DBQueryresult}    Query    ${query}
Log    ${DBQueryresult}
Set Global Variable    ${GlobalVariable}    ${DBQueryresult[0][0]}
Query    ${query2}
```

I would need to pass this  ${GlobalVariable}  in ${query2} SQL statement.

How can this be achieved or is there any other way for this solution

Comment: Did you mean fetch resulst from query1 and put it into where condition query 2 ?

Comment: Exactly @SidaraKEO

Answer (score 1):

Not totally clear on what you are trying but maybe this will help. You can imbed vars in the query strings using the ${}

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Process
Library           DatabaseLibrary
Library           Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${query}           SQL statement to fetch value from a table
${query_check}     SQL statement to check condition whether the ${query} fetch 
                   value satisfies required conditions

***Test Cases***
LINES TO CONNECT TO Db
    ${result}    Query     ${query}
    Log                    ${result}
    ${check}=              Query Check  ${DBQueryresult[0][0]}

*** Keywords ***
Query Check ${result}
    ${other_result}=       Query      New_Query_with_${result}
    [Return]   ${other_result}
```